# How to pass custom docker environment to RunConfiguration when creating a PythonScriptStep in Azure ML?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Using `RunConfiguration()` class, I used the following way to pass my custom Dockerfile for setting up the environment for the python script

```
rc = RunConfiguration()
#rc.environment.use_docker = True
rc.docker = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)
rc.environment.from_dockerfile("webscraping_env", "./Dockerfile")
```

I can see in the config file of my `rc` that docker section is:

```
"docker": {
        "arguments": [],
        "baseDockerfile": "FROM python:3.8\n\nRUN apt-get update \nRUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils\n\n#download and install chrome\nRUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb\nRUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install\n\n# install chromedriver\nRUN apt-get install -yqq unzip\nRUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip\nRUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/\n\nENV DISPLAY=:99\n\nRUN pip install selenium pandas bs4 lxml",
        "baseImage": null,
        "baseImageRegistry": {
            "address": null,
            "password": null,
            "registryIdentity": null,
            "username": null
        },
        "buildContext": null,
        "enabled": false,
        "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "Linux"
        },
        "sharedVolumes": true,
        "shmSize": "2g"
    }
```

and python section looks like this:

```
"python": {
        "baseCondaEnvironment": null,
        "condaDependencies": {
            "channels": [
                "anaconda",
                "conda-forge"
            ],
            "dependencies": [
                "python=3.8.13",
                {
                    "pip": [
                        "azureml-defaults"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name": "project_environment"
        },
        "condaDependenciesFile": null,
        "interpreterPath": "python",
        "userManagedDependencies": true
    }
```

And when I submit my pipeline consisting of single step in order to perform webscraping using selenium and bs4:

```
step = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="./webscraping-script.py",  
    source_directory=".",
    arguments=["--output_path", webscrape_ouput],
    outputs=[webscrape_ouput],
    compute_target=AmlCompute(ws, "webscrape-nb"),
    runconfig=rc,
    allow_reuse=False)
```

I get an import error informing that selenium cannot be found inside the `webscraping-script.py`. And the pipeline run stops.

I suspect that my dockerfile is not being used as an environment for running the script.

My question:
How do I achieve this? I cannot find any arguments for `PythonScriptStep` to accept an environment directly like when you pass an environment argument to `ParallelRunConfig` when setting up a `ParallelRunStep`.

I was expecting that my Dockerfile would be used as an environment for the python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in order to pass a custom docker environment, I had to create `CondaDependencies` to add the necessary pip packages and set the attributes of `RunConfiguration` to use my custom docker environment

```
run_config = RunConfiguration()
conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(pip_packages=['pandas', 'azureml-defaults', 'selenium', 'bs4', 'lxml'])
run_config.environment.python.conda_dependencies = conda_dependencies
run_config.docker.use_docker = True
run_config.environment.docker.base_image = None
run_config.environment.docker.base_dockerfile = "/path/to/Dockerfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `selenium` package to the `conda_dependencies` of your `RunConfiguration` object before submitting the pipeline. Here's an example:

```py
from azureml.core.runconfig import CondaDependencies

cd = CondaDependencies.create(pip_packages=['selenium', 'beautifulsoup4'])
rc = RunConfiguration()
rc.environment.python.conda_dependencies = cd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your custom environment from a Dockerfile and then configure RunConfiguration to use this custom environment. What is nice about registering your environment is that you can easily reuse it.

Here is the python script to create an environment:

```py
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment, BuildContext

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

ml_client = MLClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id="<your-subscription-od>",
    resource_group_name="<resource-group-name>",
    workspace_name="<your-workspace-name>",
)

env_docker_context = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(path=<path-to-your-docker-build-context>),
    name="my-custom-environment",
    description="Environment created from a Docker context.",
)
ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_context)
```

`path=<path-to-your-docker-build-context>` should be the path of your folder containing the required files to build your image + your Dockerfile. After running this script, you should be able to see your environment in the Environments tab in AzureML studio.

Then you can retrieve this environment and set up the `rc.environment` value:

```py
# Make sure you import the right modules
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep

rc = RunConfiguration()
env = Environment.get(workspace=ws, name='my-custom-environment', version='1')
rc.environment = env

step = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="./webscraping-script.py",  
    source_directory=".",
    arguments=["--output_path", webscrape_ouput],
    outputs=[webscrape_ouput],
    compute_target=AmlCompute(ws, "webscrape-nb"),
    runconfig=rc,
    allow_reuse=False)
```